Novel about time travel portals, tours to the Roman Empire, and a boy raised by Mongol warriors
The story takes place some time after a lot of time travel portals opened on Earth and wreaked havoc on the civilisation (but not catastrophically). Each portal connected two places in time-space with a fixed time offset (so if you went there and back after an hour, you arrive an hour later), but some were stable and some disappeared quickly.
A boy accidentally went into a portal when they first appeared, and ended up being raised by nomadic (Mongol? Genghis Khan?) people. However, he managed to escape in his teens and return back to present time. Now he is not socialised very well but has good combat skills.
He lives in a place "out of time" (?) - it has time portals, including back to present-day world (?), but is described as existing at a different time and possibly place.
The out-of-time place organises tours to the Roman Empire to see gladiators. The tour guides speak (and teach) Latin. During one of the excursions, they notice the "thumbs up" sign by the Emperor means "kill" (the gladiator) and not "spare".
Someone foolishly travels through an unstable portal into a different time in Africa (?) and the portal closes, stranding them there. However, they know when/where a different portal back is open, dash to it through the jungle (?) and make it back just in time.
Meta:

I don't remember the exact time I read this book; probably between 2000 and 2010.
The book was in English or Russian.
The description of TimeRiders by Alex Scarrow does not seem to match.


This is the Time Scout series by Robert Asprin and Linda Evans.

Book 1: Time Scout (1995)
Book 2: Wagers of Sin (1996)
Book 3: Ripping Time (2000)
Book 4: The House That Jack Built (2001)

An accident on an orbiting space station led to earthquakes and flooding on Earth, as well as the formation of numerous time portals, referred to as gates. These gates lead to the past and are explored and mapped by people known as time scouts.
A time scout named Skeeter Jackson (a supporting character in the first book and the protagonist of the second) fell through an unstable gate as a child and spent five years being raised by Yakka Mongols alongside an infant Genghis Khan.
Time terminals have been constructed to organise travel through certain gates, including tours to Ancient Rome. The most prominent terminal in the series, Terminal 86, is also known as Shangri-la Station or La La Land, and is located within the Tibetan Himalayas circa 1910.
During a trip to Ancient Rome in the first book, it's observed that when the Emperor gives a thumbs up at the end of a gladiatorial contest, it means that he wishes the losing gladiator to be killed rather than spared.
One of the main characters in the first book, Margo Smith, is a teenage girl who wishes to become a time scout. She travels through an unstable gate to 16th century Africa and has to be rescued by a retired time scout named Kit Carson.
The TV Tropes page contains a fair bit of info about the series and Google Books has a preview of Tales of the Time Scouts, a collection of the first two books.


All four stories are currently available from Baen Books as omnibus volumes, Tales of the Time Scouts and Tales of the Time Scouts II.

I did appreciate that one of the major reasons Margo was unlikely to succeed as a time scout was logistics, aside from general misogyny throughout time, female fashion has also tended to be much more particular, and changing, which makes costuming for the time period almost impossible.
